# Fade out animation to the right

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have bullets that fly in from the left and stop. I'd like to continue to the right and slowly fade out.  Can anyone assist with this please? I'm also open to vb code.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the bullets to stop or that you want them to stop and then continue to the right on the next trigger?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solid background color, you can:

Add a rectangle that covers, say, the right quarter of the screen.
Give it a gradient fill from any color on the left to the same color as the b/g on the right.
Make the any-color portion of the gradient 100% transparent.

Now, when you animate your text off, it'll gradually seem to fade as it moves underneath the background colored portion of the rectangle.